# Angular resize service

Tags: angular, typescript, components, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to create an observable that will emit a value of true or false if the window screen is less than 520px or not.
So I have this code below:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResizeService {
  private mobileView$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  mobileViewObs$ = this.mobileView$.asObservable();
  isMobile = false;
  size!: {width: number, height: number};
  constructor() {
   }

  resizeEvent(){
     fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(throttleTime(500), debounceTime(500)).subscribe((resizeEvent: any) => {
      this.size = {
          width: +resizeEvent.currentTarget.innerWidth,
          height: +resizeEvent.currentTarget.innerHeight
      }; 
      
      this.isMobile = this.isMobileView(this.size);

      this.mobileView$.next(this.isMobile);
    });;
  }

  isMobileView(size: {width: number, height: number}){
    if(size.width < PHONE_SIZE.width && size.height < PHONE_SIZE.height){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

It is working fine, but the problem is I can't set the initial size of a page. I don't know how to send the size object from the component to the service. Here is my component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-books-list',
  templateUrl: './books-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./books-list.component.scss'],
})
export class BooksListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() book!: BookModel;

  booksArray: BookModel[] = [];
  oneBook!: BookModel;
  isMobile: boolean = false;
  size!: {width: number, height: number};

  constructor(private service: BookService, private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private resizeService: ResizeService) {}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.size = {width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight};
    
    this.resizeService.resizeEvent();
    this.resizeService.mobileViewObs$.subscribe(data => {
      this.isMobile = data;
    })

    this.service.getBooks().subscribe((books) => {
      this.booksArray = books;
    });
  }
```

The problem is that the first time the page reload it will always diplay false because the observable is created only on resize event. Do you know how to implement this feature?

Comment: please paste your code with the triple backticks wrappers ` ` ` code ` ` ` (with no spaces in between)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that much code actually, you can just assign the `true` or `false` directly in the service to an observable, to which you in the component subscribe. Assumingly you want to show different content in template depending on mobile/desktop view, so it's a perfect scenario to use the `async` pipe!

If you need the `true`/`false` in the component ts, you can of course subscribe to it, but remember to **unsubscribe** if that is the path you are taking!

Anyways, I suggest the following...

SERVICE:

```ts
isMobile$ = fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(
  startWith(window), // to have an initial value, can be any value
  mapTo(window), // map to window object instead (so we can have the initial value!)
  throttleTime(500),
  debounceTime(500),
  map((window: Window) => {
    if (window.innerWidth < PHONE_SIZE.width && window.innerHeight < PHONE_SIZE.height) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  })
);
```

And in the component you simply do....

```ts
isMobile$ = this.resizeService.isMobile$;
```

Then either use the `async` pipe or subscribe!

**[HERE'S A DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ud8scg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** - here only the screen width is taken into consideration for easy testing :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code is pretty clean. But can you explain me please why I need to use mapTo(window) operator in the pipe? Is it because the observable emits an Event object and I actually need a windows object? Sorry, I'm new to RxJS and I think all this operators really got me...

Comment: As comment I added, map to window, so we can have the initial value. If you remove `startWith` and `mapTo` it won't trigger initially as resize hasn't happen when page loads. We use `window` here as when page loads, there is no resize event available (yet) as resize hasn't happened

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`. You need to get the size when the component is starting to render. However, `ngOnInit` is used to initialized all data-bound properties.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-books-list',
  templateUrl: './books-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./books-list.component.scss'],
})
export class BooksListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() book!: BookModel;

  booksArray: BookModel[] = [];
  oneBook!: BookModel;
  isMobile: boolean = false;
  size!: {width: number, height: number};

  constructor(private service: BookService, private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private resizeService: ResizeService) {}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.size = {width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight};
    

    this.service.getBooks().subscribe((books) => {
      this.booksArray = books;
    });

   ngAfterViewInit() {
   // removed this from ViewInit
   this.resizeService.resizeEvent();
    this.resizeService.mobileViewObs$.subscribe(data => {
      this.isMobile = data;
    })
    }
  }
```

Check [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) for more details on how to use Lifecycle hooks.